# Background tasks in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm

I'm wondering, is there any way to implement background tasks?
Maybe with workers pool. Can you show me direction, I'm thinking about writing package for this?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

### 2019 update

Before thinking about writing a package for anything, first look if there are existing packages that do what you need. In the Meteor world, this means looking on Atmosphere for "job/queue/task/worker management/scheduling" packages, then on npm for the same search terms. You also need to define your requirements more precisely:

- do you want persistence, or would an in-memory solution work?
- do you want to be able to distribute jobs to different machines?

### Meteor-specific

- [job-collection](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection/) - reliable (I used it in 2014 in production at a startup), but currently in maintenance mode. Lets you schedule persistent jobs to be run anywhere (servers, clients).
- [SteveJobs](https://github.com/msavin/stevejobs) - actively maintained by Max Savin, the author of several [powerful Meteor tools](http://www.maxsavin.com/)
- [littledata:synced-cron](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron/) - "A simple cron system for Meteor. It supports syncronizing jobs between multiple processes."

*Abandoned packages:*

- [artwells:queue](https://atmospherejs.com/artwells/queue) - priorities, scheduling, logging, re-queuing. Queue backed by MongoDB. Last [code commit](https://github.com/artwells/meteor-queue/commits/master): 2015-Oct.
- super basic cron packages: [easycron](https://atmospherejs.com/chfritz/easycron). Last update: Dec 2015.
- [differential:workers](https://atmospherejs.com/differential/workers) - Spawn headless worker meteor processes to work on async jobs. Last [code commit](https://github.com/Differential/meteor-workers/commits/master): Jan 2015
- [cron](https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/cron) ([since 2015](https://github.com/alexsuslov/Meteor.cron))
- [PowerQueue](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-power-queue) - abandoned [since 2014](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-power-queue/commits/master). Queue async tasks, throttle resource usage, retry failed. Supports sub queues. [No scheduling](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-power-queue/issues/15). No tests, but [nifty demo](http://power-queue-test.meteor.com/). Not suitable for running for a long while due to using [recursive calls](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-power-queue/issues/31).

### Npm packages

Meteor has been able to use npm packages directly for several years now, so this question amounts to finding [job/worker/queue management packages](https://github.com/sindresorhus/awesome-nodejs#job-queues) on NPM. If you don't care about persistence:

- [Async](https://caolan.github.io/async) "provides around 70 functions that include the usual 'functional' suspects (`map`, `reduce`, `filter`, `each`...) as well as some common patterns for asynchronous control flow (`parallel`, `series`, `waterfall`...)"
- [d3-queue](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue) - minimalistic, written by D3 author Mike Bostock

If you do want persistence, since Meteor uses MongoDB already, it may be advantageous to use a job scheduling package with persistence to MongoDb. The most powerful and popular seems to be [Agenda](https://github.com/agenda/agenda), but unfortunately it hasn't been maintained in months, and it has a significant backlog of [issues](https://github.com/agenda/agenda/issues).

If you're willing to add a dependency backed by [redis](http://redis.io/) to your project, there are more choices:

- [bull](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bull#feature-comparison) - the most full-featured job queue solution for Node, backed by Redis
- [bee](https://github.com/bee-queue/bee-queue) - simple, fast, robust. Does not suffer from a [memory leak that Bull exhibits](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/issues/1110#issuecomment-436473121)
- [Kue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kue) - priority job queue for Node

Like MongoDB, Redis can also provide high-availability (via Redis Sentinel), and if you want to distribute jobs among multiple worker machines, you can [point them all at the same Redis server](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/issues/873#issuecomment-437445002).

Comment: This one looks pretty popular: https://atmospherejs.com/percolatestudio/synced-cron

Comment: This is a phenomenal list, thanks for keeping it up to date, a real service.

Comment: This package seams interesting: https://atmospherejs.com/differential/workers
I didn't try it yet but I wanted to mention it to increase the options list

Comment: @DanDascalescu I'm yet to do a full write-up on this one - but you can use celeryproject.org (Distributed task queue built on Python & RabbitMQ) - there's a meteor package we're currently using - https://atmospherejs.com/3stack/celery (See also https://atmospherejs.com/3stack/celery-connect for an easier setup)

Comment: @chmac: It would be easier to keep it up-to-date [if SO editing worked properly](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326100/useful-edit-rejected-by-editors-not-familiar-with-the-topic).

Comment: Thanks for sharing such a complete list!

Comment: I'm curious about `Kue` being marked as *avoid* - the meteor package wrapper is deprecated, sure, but kue is still a great (non-meteor) option

Comment: @zeroasterisk: thanks for the prompt. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is a package based on Cron jobs which can be used to schedule tasks on certain intervals or dates. Here is the package: https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/cron

And if you happen to look into the source of that package, you'll notice they're simply using:

`Meteor.setInterval( ... , delay );`

So if you save your tasks in a database, then load them into intervals during startup, then you'll probably be on the right track.

Comment: And there is a good possibility that those calls in the cron package can and should be changed to Meteor.setTimeout() calls.

Comment: The only issue is these intervals would run on each server. My new package, Steve Jobs, takes care of this issue and other issues. 
See https://github.com/msavin/SteveJobs..meteor.jobs.scheduler.queue.background.tasks

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for something that is specific to Meteor, I am happy to share there is a new package called Steve Jobs. It makes running background jobs as easy as calling a Method.

It has all the standard features you would expect, such as running a job only once, retrying failed jobs, and so on. You can learn more about it on GitHub:

http://github.com/msavin/stevejobs

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing proper support is on their roadmap, but in the meantime I've managed to get it going in a hacky way via `setInterval`. See the [cron-tick](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/cron-tick) package.