# setInterval with a variable interval

Tags: coffeescript, meteor, settimeout, setinterval

I would like an api call to be done immediately, then after 1sec, then 2sec, etc in incrementations of 1 sec up to 10.

I tried something like this:

```
Meteor.startup ->
  counter = 1000
  Meteor.setInterval (->
    Meteor.call "call_url", url, (err, result) ->
        ...

    if counter < 10000
      counter += 1000
      console.log counter
  ), counter
```

While my counter is incremented, the log is done exactly every seconds, which means that the **setInterval** doesn't keep track of the value.

The only way I see to handle this would be having 9 **setTimeout** to call the api at different times, then a **Meteor.setInterval** starting after all the timeouts... Sounds very ugly.

Any suggestions on how to do this in a clean way? It's important for the user to see frequent updates when he just connects to the page, but if he decides to let it open for a while, there is no need to perform that api query so often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more general solution (and scalable in the future for CoinsManager) is to use a queuing package that supports scheduling events in the future. I've looked at a bunch of [background task management for Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21351966/1269037), and [queue](http://beta.atmospherejs.com/package/queue) supports scheduling.

Comment: Hi Dan, this looks like a good idea, but more fit for server calls. Here, the api calls are all done [on the client](https://github.com/Fandekasp/CoinsManager/blob/feature/coins_value/app/client/helpers/autorun.coffee) (depending on each client visible addresses, not saving anything in the db). dbarrett suggested me to go this way: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7025613/, and maybe make it smarter by checking for window focus

Answer (score 0):

Not quite clear what you are asking and there are probably a lot of ways to generate the intervals you want.

In javascript it might look like this:

```
var doStuff = function(){...};
var intervals = [ 1000, 3000, 6000, 10000, 15000, 21000, 28000, 36000, 45000, 55000 ];

doStuff();  //run immediately
intervals.forEach( function( interval ){
  Meteor.setTimeout( doStuff, interval );
});
```