# Schedule in meteor

Tags: meteor, scheduler

Is there a best practice to schedule some task to a specified date and hour in meteor (e.g. what buffer doe with tweets)? I thought of a collection (sendlater) that contains all the info needed (date, time, code to run). And a server code that checks (maybe every minute) if there are codes to run, and runs them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Background tasks in Meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703010/background-tasks-in-meteor)

Comment: Thanks! [jobCollection](http://atmospherejs.com/package/jobCollection) seems solving scheduling (though only in experimental phase).