# How to run code on a separate node? Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, settimeout

I've got this tournament hosting website that has to keep track of tournament start times and round limits.
Currently I do this by using Meteor.setIntervals. The biggest problem with this is that every time I have to redeploy I lose all the timers... (kind of ruins the benefit of hot code pushes).
Is there a way to run my timers on something separate that doesn't get killed on deploy?

Comment: See [Background tasks in Meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703010/background-tasks-in-meteor). You'll probably be best off using a dedicated library for this, and the accepted answer mentions a lot of options.

Comment: https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron what about this package??

Comment: I tried using synced cron. Unfortunately you can only run cron jobs down the the minute so round times and start times will be off by up to 1 minute. I cant set crons to run at a specific second :/