# How can I run a task inside a meteor method without waiting for it to complete?

Tags: meteor, queue

I have several function calls in a row that run and wait to return, then the next one runs. After these are run I have one function I want to run, but then I don't want to wait for it to be done before I run my return.

Here is an example of what I mean.

`get_card`, `create_order`, `create_association` and `debit_order` all need to wait for the previous function to complete before they can run. When I get to `Queue.start_account_creation_task` I want it to start running, but then let the return on the line below run right away too.

```
Meteor.methods({
    singleDonation: function (data) {
        logger.info("Started singleDonation");

                //Get the card data from balanced and store it
                var card = Utils.get_card(customerData._id, data.paymentInformation.href);

                //Create a new order
                var orders = Utils.create_order(data._id, customerData.href);

                //Associate the card with the balanced customer
                var associate = Utils.create_association(customerData._id, card.href, customerData.href);

                //Debit the order
                var debitOrder = Utils.debit_order(data.paymentInformation.total_amount, data._id, customerData._id, orders.href, card.href);

            Queue.start_account_creation_task(customerData._id, data._id, debitOrder._id);
            return {c: customerData._id, don: data._id, deb: debitOrder._id};
    }
});
```

Comment: https://meteorhacks.com/fibers-eventloop-and-meteor.html

Comment: @Sindis Can you give me a hint here? I've looked at this article and I don't see how I could use this. Mostly it is talking about doing the opposite of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Try wrapping all actions that need to wait for each other into one fiber

Comment: @Sindis I need to return to the client before the last function is completed. I don't think wrapping in a fiber will do since I need to wait for all of the previous work to complete before starting the last function.

Comment: Maybe you can try callbacks in every function. If it wont work I can't help you further

Comment: @Sindis. This won't work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that seemed to work the best for what I was trying to do was to just use a `Meteor.setTimeout({})`. It might seem like an odd choice, but it does everything I needed, including setting the Meteor Environment so that I didn't have to do any BindEnrironment call. It also breaks out of the current thread of calls, which means it then returns the result to the client and a second later finishes the rest of the calls (which are to external APIs that I didn't need my users sitting there waiting for).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need parallel and serial control for tasks. *The* (as in, 400,000 downloads a day) Node.js module for that is called [`async`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async), and a Meteor wrapper for it is [peerlibrary:async](https://atmospherejs.com/peerlibrary/async).

Sooner or later you'll need a dedicated background task management package. If async is insufficient, have a look at my evaluation of [packages to control background tasks in Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703010/background-tasks-in-meteor).

Comment: I was actually able to solve my problem by using this.

Meteor.setTimeout(function(){
                Utils.create_user(customerData._id, data._id, debitOrder._id);
            }, 100);

Comment: I really need to learn more about what is going on here, but I think the reason this works is that the task is both async and meteor takes care of the bindEnvironment so that I still get all of my variable references passed to it. Does that sound about right?

Comment: setTimeout didn't work for me because the function I call uses Fibers / Future. The async module works and feels less hacky.