# Perform large operations in Meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I am doing some operations on a rather big collection in Meteor. I perform some updates on different collections. I know from VBA that I can turn of screenupdating and calculation before performing large tasks and turn it back on when I'm finish. Should I do something similar in Meteor? I am not interested in seeing the numbers change on the page while the operations are being performed since the numbers are not relevant/meaningful before all the operations are finish.

Comment: Well anyway if you block the event loop it's going to freeze, so...

Answer (score 0):

Because Meteor is single threaded it's not possible to "freeze screen update" in Meteor itself.

But it seems there is a [plugin](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection) for that.

There is also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703010/background-tasks-in-meteor) question that discusses background tasks in Meteor.